# Sorting a list, ignoring every nth element?

Tags: c#

I have a list (I can implement it as whatever type of collection gives a succinct solution) like this:

```
4,1,5,2,1,3,8,1,6,4,2,3
```

The list is actually groups of 3 values and it's length will always be a multiple of 3.  There is no relationship between the first 2 values of the group and the 3rd value of the group.

I would like to sort the array such that every 3rd value is left in place.  For the example I've given, the result would be:

```
1,1,5,1,2,3,2,4,6,4,8,3
```

The elements with indices 0,1,3,4,6 and 7 have been sorted.  The elements with indices 2,5 and 8 have not been sorted.

Another way to express this is to imagine that the list is x,x,y,x,x,y,x,x,y,x,x,y and I want to sort only the xs.

I can write an algorithm but wonder if there is succinct way of doing this?

Comment: This may be more appropriate on code review (after you suggest/write an algorithm).

Comment: @flem  I take your point, but surely one of the purposes of SO is to learn and advance?  Writing the algorithm is trivial.  My purpose is to seek a more succinct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're desperately keen to do this really efficiently, I would go for a *simple* solution:

- Extract the elements you want to sort into a new list
- Sort the list
- Either build a new list merging the elements you want to sort with the fixed ones, or (if you prefer to use mutable collections) just put the sorted elements back into the original list.

So something like:

```
var list = ...; // Get hold of the whole list.
var sortedElements = list.Where((value, index) => index % 3 != 2)
                         .OrderBy(x => x)
                         .ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < sortedElements.Count; i++)
{
    int index = (i / 2) * 3 + i % 2;
    list[index] = sortedElements[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you John.  Initial comments (since deleted) asked me to "show me what you did first" and I was so frustrated that I started to write the algorithm.  Just about to test when I saw this response but I can now move from 2 fugly `for` loops, building 2 lists then remerging, to a more elegant approach which is what I was seeking.  Thanks again, I've learned something and have a new tool!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try following linq

```
var ints = new int[]{4,1,5,2,1,3,8,1,6,4,2,3};
var result = ints.Where((i,j) => j%3!= 2).OrderBy(i=>i).ToArray();

var index = ints.Select ((i , j)=> 
    {
        if (j%3==2) 
            return i; 
        else 
            return result[(j/3)*2 + j%3];
    });
```

How it works
1. Take sorted array ignoring non required values
2.  Prepare output array from original array with first 2 values of each triplet from sorted array.

Comment: Thank you.  I wish I could accept 2 answers.  I like the use of LINQ here but I do think that John Skeet's solution is easier to read (for sure, one day someone else is going to have to read this).  For this reason, I accept John's solution and upvoted yours.  Thanks again.

Comment: He is Jon, and not John. Upvote that answer also. It is always nice to have multiple answers, and that is the beauty of the forum.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that taking out every third value, and keeping it seperately, then sort everything and insert the values again would the simplest.

```
numbers.Where((n, index) => (index + 1) % 3 == 0);
numbers.Where((n, index) => (index + 1) % 3 != 0);
```

This gives you lists of the thrid indexes and what needs to be sorted.